# What's the most concise way to get a newline-separated string representation of a numpy array?

Tags: python

I need to pass as `stdin` to a process a list of floats and this is done from Python e.g.

```
arr = np.array(range(1,11))
# TODO: how to convert from arr to '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n'
proc = subprocess.Popen(["./myproc"],stdin=StringIO('1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n'),stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

What's the simplest way to convert from:

```
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

to

```
'1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.array(range(1,11))
print "\n".join(str(n) for n in a)
```

or

```
print "\n".join(map(str,a))
```

Notes:

1. In Python, the [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method is defined on strings and takes an iterable containing strings
2. `"\n".join(a)` gives a TypeError because a contains int not string
3. You can simply `print a` or `str(a)` but the formatting will not include the newlines

Comment: `("".join([str(f)+"\n" for f in a]))` to get a newline after the last number also